# using pattern and matcher to get specific values from string

Tags: java, design-patterns, pattern-matching

I want to use pattern that return to me the (**ssid**, **psk**, **proiority**) as *key*
and the *value* associated for each *key*.
and if there is a way to understand the expressions that i have to use
like

```
Pattern.compile("(\\w+?):(\\w+?),")
```

reply to me.

this is my String

```
network={
     ssid="name"
     psk="password"
     key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
     priority=1
}

network={
     ssid="another name"
     psk="another password"
     key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
     priority=1
}
```

Comment: did you just format it with line breaks or is it that way?

Comment: it is like that.. wpa_supplicant.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ugly solution:

I put your text input into a file named `file.txt` and read it through a BufferedReader

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("src/test/file.txt");
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String temp;
        String result = "";
        while ((temp = read.readLine()) != null) {
            result += temp;
        }
        result = result.replaceAll("\\{", " ");
        result = result.replaceAll("\\}", " ");
        result = result.replaceAll("network=", " ");
        result = result.trim();

        String[] list = result.split("[ ]+(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
        for (String s : list) {
            s = s.trim();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)=(.*)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("Key: " + m.group(1));
                System.out.println("Value: " + m.group(2));
            }
        }

    }
```

This is my output:

```
Key: ssid
Value: "name"
Key: psk
Value: "password"
Key: key_mgmt
Value: WPA-PSK
Key: priority
Value: 1
Key: ssid
Value: "another name"
Key: psk
Value: "another password"
Key: key_mgmt
Value: WPA-PSK
Key: priority
Value: 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot .. its work for me but if their is a better way please write it .